# Oracle SQL: How to display in two columns the results of a column without duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I'm trying to display in two columns the results from orderNumber column in the orders table for orders that have the same orderDate.
In the table I have the following data:

```
OrderNumber     OrderDate
------------    ----------
1               2013-06-01
2               2013-06-02
3               2013-06-03
4               2013-07-05
5               2013-07-09
6               2013-07-09
7               2013-07-15
8               2013-07-15
```

I need to display in two columns the orderNumber with the same orderDate without duplicates.
I've used this query:

```
SELECT O1.OrderNumber, O2.OrderNumber, O1.OrderDate FROM Orders O1, Orders O2
WHERE O1.OrderNumber <> O2.OrderNumber AND O1.OrderDate = O2.OrderDate
```

I get the following results:

```
OrderNumber     OrderNumber   OrderDate
-----------     -----------   ---------
3               2             2013-06-02
2               3             2013-06-02
6               5             2013-07-09
5               6             2013-07-09
8               7             2013-07-15
7               8             2013-07-15 

this shows that the second line is a duplicate of the first, the fourth the duplicate of the third and the so on.

I want to only keep half of the results

OrderNumber     OrderNumber   OrderDate
-----------     -----------   ---------
3               2             2013-06-02
6               5             2013-07-09
8               7             2013-07-15
```

or

```
OrderNumber     OrderNumber   OrderDate
-----------     -----------   ---------
2               3             2013-06-02
5               6             2013-07-09
7               8             2013-07-15
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Misael

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`WHERE O1.OrderNumber <> O2.OrderNumber ...`

use

`WHERE O1.OrderNumber > O2.OrderNumber...`